# How to pass a non-evaluated expression of boolean condition to a function?

Tags: c, function, arguments, parameter-passing, dry

The code that I have written below below repeats itself 3 times:

```
int foo = 3;
while (foo < 10) {
    printf("Hi!");
    foo++;
}
foo = 12;
while (foo % 8 != 0) {
    printf("Hi!");
    foo++;
}
foo = 25
while (foo <= 38) {
    printf("Hi!");
    foo++;
}
```

This could be simplified to function bar (foo, *condition*); This function would look like as follows:

```
while (foo <= 38) {
    printf("Hi!");
    foo++;
}
```

and I would call it like this:

```
print_hi(3, foo < 10);
print_hi(12, foo % 8 != 0);
print_hi(25, foo <= 38);
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to pass boolean condition to function?

As a close alternative, code can use function pointers.  Form that *condition* as a function.

```
bool f_lt(int a, int b) {
  return (a < b);
}

bool f_rem(int a, int b); // definition left for OP
bool f_le(int a, int b); // definition left for OP

void print_hi(int foo, int bar, bool (*condition)(int, int));
  while(condition(foo, bar)){
    printf("Hi!");
    foo++;
  }
}
```

Call them as:

```
print_hi(3, 10, f1_lt);
print_hi(12, 8, f1_rem);
print_hi(25, 38, f1_le);
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution as in the answer of chux, only in the syntax maybe a little closer to the desired form asked in the question.

How does it work:

EXPR is a macro with two parameters. The first parameter is the name of the function pointer. The second is the expression to be evaluated. The function does nothing else but execute the expression and return the bool result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define EXPR(a, b) bool (a)(int foo) { return (b); }

void print_hi(int foo, bool (*expr_ptr)(int)) {
    while (expr_ptr(foo)) {
        printf("Hi!");
        foo++;
    }
}

EXPR(expr1, foo < 10)
EXPR(expr2, foo % 8 != 0)
EXPR(expr3, foo <= 38)

int main(void) {
    print_hi(3, expr1);
    print_hi(12, expr2);
    print_hi(25, expr3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> "How to pass boolean condition to function?"

The problem in this case is, that it is not only a boolean *condition*. The given *expression* which yields the boolean value needs to be proofed inside of the function after each iteration.

You cannot pass non-evaluated expressions to a function.

If the boolean expressions are constant and limited to only the three you provided in the example and you explicitly want to use the expression in the function call (to maintain readability), you can use a string literal and compare the string literal inside of the function as alternative instead. Note that you need to surround the expression by `""`, like `"exp"` in this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_hi(int, const char const *);

int main(void)
{
   print_hi(3, "val < 10");
   print_hi(12, "val % 8 != 0");
   print_hi(25, "val <= 38");

   return 0;
}

void print_hi(int val, const char const * str)
{
   int exp = 0;

   if(strcmp(str, "val < 10") == 0);
   {
       exp = 1;
   }
   else if(strcmp(str, "val % 8 != 0") == 0);
   {
       exp = 2;  
   }
       else if(strcmp(str, "val <= 38") == 0)
       {
          exp = 3;
       }
          else
            return;

   switch(exp)
   {
      case 1:
      while (val < 10) 
      {
         printf("Hi!");
         val++;
      }      
      break;

      case 2:
      while (val % 8 != 0)
      {
        printf("Hi!");
        val++;
      }
      break;

      case 3:
      while (val <= 38) {
        printf("Hi!");
        val++;
      }
      break;

      default:
      break;
   }

   return;
}
```

Or you also could just use a value for it as alternative and inside of the function decide the path based on this value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_hi(int, unsigned short int);

int main(void)
{
   print_hi(3,1);
   print_hi(12,2);
   print_hi(25,3);

   return 0;
}

void print_hi(int val, unsigned short int exp)
{
   switch(exp)
   {
      case 1:
      while (val < 10) 
      {
         printf("Hi!");
         val++;
      }      
      break;

      case 2:
      while (val % 8 != 0)
      {
        printf("Hi!");
        val++;
      }
      break;

      case 3:
      while (val <= 38) {
        printf("Hi!");
        val++;
      }
      break;

      default:
      break;
   }

   return;
}
```